# Wagtail ListBlock - how to access first (any) element in template?

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

I have ListBlock called `images`in Wagtail. It works well. If I put

> {{ page.images }}

in a template, it render the html code like:

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li> 
</ul>
```

But I am unable to find out how to get the first item of the list isolated. Or at least how to iterate over the list manually.

I am pretty sure the solution is simple, however I am unable to google it, find in the docs, or understand from the wagtail source.

Comment: You can get a searchable list of the block, then get the first element like this: `{% page.images.get_searchable_content|first %}`, but depending on what you are trying to do, there may be an easier way.

Comment: `{% page.images %}` doesn't look like valid code to me. Are you sure that's what you're using?

Comment: @gasman Fair point, corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't shared your model definition, but I'm going to guess it's something like:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    images = StreamField([
        ('image_list', blocks.ListBlock(blocks.ImageChooserBlock)),
    ])
```

Using the standard pattern for [manually looping over a StreamField value](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering) as shown in the Wagtail docs, this would be:

```
{% for block in page.images %}
    {% if block.block_type == 'image_list' %}
        {# at this point block.value gives you the images as an ordinary Python list #}

        {# Output the first image using block.value.0: #}
        {% image block.value.0 width-800 %}

        {# Or loop over block.value manually with a 'for' loop #}
        <ul>
            {% for img in block.value %}
                <li>{% image img width-800 %}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    {% elif block.block_type == 'some_other_block' %}
        ...
    {% else %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, you probably only have one block type defined (`image_list`), so the `if block.block_type == 'image_list'` can be left out; but you'll still need the outer `{% for block in page.images %}`, because StreamField is still defined as a list of blocks, even if you only have one item in that list.

Comment: Is there any way to only output the latest 12 images in the template?